# Listagg in cursor in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, cursor, listagg

Im trying to create a cursor fetch_table_info that uses the LISTAGG in its select statement.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE testcheck is 
cursor fetch_table_info is       
select LISTAGG(B.COLUMN_NAME,'||'',''||')       
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B.COLUMN_POSITION)       
from USER_IND_COLUMNS B       
where  B.TABLE_NAME=B.INDEX_NAME and b.TABLE_NAME='TEST_TAB'; 
begin 
dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM); 
end; 
/
```

The select statement executes fine individually, but compiling the procedure is giving the below error

**Found 'LISTAGG', Only CUME_DIST, DENSE_RANK, PERCENT_RANK, RANK, PERCENTILE_CONT and PERCENTILE_DISC are valid with WITHIN GROUP**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using an older version of Toad that doesn't recognise the `listagg` function introduced in Oracle 11gR2.

[From the Dell support site](https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/60825):

> Description
>   The 11gR2 new analytic function LISTAGG is not recognised by syntax checker.
>
> ...
>
> The code above runs ok but if we try to format it, the following error message appears:
>
> ERROR line 4, col 10, ending_line 4, ending_col 16, Found listagg, Only CUME_DIST, DENSE_RANK, PERCENT_RANK, RANK, PERCENTILE_CONT and PERCENTILE_DISC are valid with WITHIN GROUP
>
> Cause
>   The parser in version 10.1 does not support this 11gR2 function
>
> Resolution
>    Toad for Oracle 11.0 and above support this. You can download the latest version of Toad using http://bit.ly/noHL20

... which amusingly points to an old Quest URL that just redirects to the Dell support landing page. Looks like you can [get the current version here](https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/12.8).

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11gR2 and Toad for Oracle 9.7. The select query is working fine if I execute it independently. Why is it not working only in a procedure?

Comment: That linked support note says the same thing, sort of: "The code above runs ok but if we try to format it, the following error message appears". Maybe some formatting is being done automatically for PL/SQL, or they both go through some common syntax checker that isn't hit for a single simple SQL statement. I have no idea, you'd need to take it up with Dell, but I imagine they'd just tell you to upgrade...